# Windows Python Gtk: Check the pressed key is 'enter' key or not

Tags: python, windows, gtk

I am using python 2.7 with Gtk 2 on windows machine.
I tried the following code to detect the enter key is pressed in the window. But it shows **no such module Gdk**.

```
import gtk;
import gtk.glade;
import gtk.gdk;
...
if event.keyval == Gdk.KEY_Enter:
      print "ENTER Key pressed";
```

I tried installing Gdk module with gi module, but that is also not working.

Is there any other way we can do the same check without using the **Gdk** module?

Comment: You import it as `gtk.gdk` but you try to use it as `Gdk`. This does not work. So either you change your import to `import gtk.gdk as Gdk` or  you write `gtk.gdk.KEY_Enter`.
Apart from that, `Gdk.KEY_Enter` does not exist (even if it is correctly imported) and if you want to use gi then you have to use python3.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback elya. Is there a way, we can achieve the same functionality in python2.7 ?

Comment: In gi there is `Gdk.KEY_Return` but I cannot find for pygtk. Otherwise, you can just use the integer value `65293`.

Answer (score 0):

You imported gtk.gdk but not gi.repository.Gdk.  To see if the key is enter, however, you should check to see if event.keyval is equal to gtk.keysyms.Return